# Comparing enum values in C#/Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

I was wondering if it is possible to compare the (int) of two seperate Enums (from different scripts)?

I am currently trying:

```
 if((int)newMiner.minerType == (int)resourceType)
        {
            Debug.Log("Resource Holder Accepts Miner");
        }
```

newMiner is the other script that has the enum I'm trying to compare and minerType is one Enum while resourceType is the local Enum I am trying to compare it with.

What I have now does not return an error, however, it always returns true. Any information on how this does/doesn't work would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: What does your newMiner look like and what does your resourceType enum look like? You should post both of these.

Comment: Can you paste the enum declarations? I suspect that whatever is under minerType and resourceType doesn't actually correspond to each other.

Comment: Theoretically, yes you can cast an `Enum` to an int and compare them.  But an `Enum` could also use `[Flags]` (think multiple values at once) which totally breaks this. Plus each `Enum` must match in terms of their numerical values for this to be of any use.  Also, why not put a breakpoint and see what integers you are getting from both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this.

Just have one publicly-available enum!  Use the same in both places.

Answer (score 9):

Let's say you have two enums

```
enum Car { Window, Door, Light, Gate, Bath }

enum House { Window, Door, Light, Bath, Gate }
```

Then you have instance of them with

```
Car car = Car.Window;
House house = House.Window;
```

Can you compare them directly with `if (car == house)`?

**NO**

Can you compare their values with `if ((int)car == (int)house)`?

**Yes**. It looks like this is what you are trying to do.

*Example 1*:

```
if ((int)car == (int)house)
    Debug.Log("Car Value matches House value");
else
    Debug.Log("Car Value DOES NOT match House value");
```

Output:

> Car Value matches House value

That's because `Window` from `Car` Enum and `Window` from `House` Enum both share the-same Enum value index which is `0`.

*Example 2*:

```
Car car = Car.Light;
House house = House.Light;

if ((int)car == (int)house)
    Debug.Log("Car Value matches House value");
else
    Debug.Log("Car Value DOES NOT match House value");
```

Output:

> Car Value matches House value

Again, that's because `Light` from `Car` Enum and `Light` from `House` Enum both share the-same Enum value index which is `2`.

*Example 3*:

```
Car car = Car.Gate;
House house = House.Gate;

if ((int)car == (int)house)
    Debug.Log("Car Value matches House value");
else
    Debug.Log("Car Value DOES NOT match House value");
```

Output:

> Car Value DOES NOT match House value

Surprise! Surprise! Gate and Gate from `Car` and `House` Enum don't match. **Why?**

Because `Gate` from `House` Enum has a value of `4` and while `Gate` from `Car` Enum has a value of `3`. **4 != 3**.

When you cast Enum to int, you will get its index position of it. The position starts from `0` like an array. For example, the Enum declaration code below shows you what the index looks like.

```
enum Car { Window = 0, Door = 1, Light = 2, Gate = 3, Bath = 4 }
```

For the if statement to be `true`, they both have to be at the-same position. You will get `false` if they are in different position. Check your Enum again and fix that.

Comment: Excellent explanation, except that the value of an enum member is not always its index (that's just the value by default if no values are explicitly assigned). And of course flag enumerations are a whole other kettle of fish.

Comment: Yes, yes, You are right. I wrote this assuming the default value. As for the flags, yes, it is a different whole thing but OP didn't mention Flags so its safe to just assume that OP is just trying to compare values in two different Enums.